# jquery validate - redefine registration/settings after initial call to validate()?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am running into issues with using the jquery validate plugin on a page where I am asynchronously loading content with .load(). I am reloading a section of the page where my registered errorContainer exists, and I can't figure out a way to re-register the setting after the content is loaded with another call to validate(). I took a look at the internals of the plugin and it looks like the initialization/registration of the settings and properties isn't happening in the validate method because the validator object exists and the initialization is skipped over. Is there any supported way to reregister or edit these settings? I am using version 1.8.1.

Edit: I understand I can probably work around this by using the showErrors callback or using some custom css class to position the auto-generated label where I need it, but I'm interested in knowing if there is a way to maintain the use of errorContainer by modifying the setting I've provided in validate() without having to resort to a workaround.

Comment: Have you tried to remove "validator" data in your form with $form.removeData("validator") and recall the initialization method ($form.validate(your_optionts))?

Comment: Yeah, I was considering doing that (or removing/modifying specific settings in case other validators existed in the content that is not changing) but I felt that that was tinkering around inside of the plugin too much. It should work and may come to that though.

Comment: if use [addClassRules](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addClassRules) should it work also with dynamic content. Have you tried?

Comment: addClassRules does work for applying rules to dynamic elements, but the settings object/form data implementation is really the source of my issue which generally isn't affected by addClassRules. If the form data for validator already exists when validate() is called, it is returned and no re-initialization of the validator occurs. It might be a useful feature if you could choose to reinitialize the validator as needed.

Comment: @Fabio, he's not talking about changing the rules, which would be easy.  He wants to change the options, which is impossible.

Comment: **Quote OP**:  _"I am using version 1.8.1"_  ~ The plugin is up to version 1.13 and a whole lot of bugs have been fixed since 1.8.

Comment: Fair enough, but I've taken a look at the most current release and even pending edits on github and the implementations for both the settings/validator initialization and the errorContainer initialization are the same as the version I'm using.

Comment: Of course if this was an option in a newer version, I'd have mentioned it.  My point is simply that you're using a very old version full of unrelated bugs that have since been fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The short answer is "no".**

Once the `.validate()` method is invoked, the plugin is initialized.  Since any subsequent call to `.validate()` is ignored, there is no way to change any of the options.  There are no workarounds.

The only exception to this are the `rules` & `messages` options which can be modified at any time using [the `.rules('add')` and `.rules('remove')` methods](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/).

---

Any contact with the developer, bug reports, feature requests, etc, should be done at his GitHub page:

https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues

Comment: Good to know. If the settings can't be changed, I may make a feature request asking that the errorContainer's initialization/conversion to a jQuery object happen as late as possible or even during the validation method to support situations where the errorContainer DOM element may be disposed and recreated.

Comment: @moarboilerplate, yes, you would do that over here:  https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues ~ might as well just request that any option be disposed and recreated.

Comment: I was able to get at the settings object with $("#form").validate().settings, but tread lightly...

Comment: @moarboilerplate,  yes, but can you edit them and have the new settings take effect?

Comment: I haven't tested for all settings, but it worked for the errorPlacement callback--the init() function just extends the internal settings object (validate().settings) with the errorPlacement property so it's the same as accessing it directly and adding the property manually. If there are settings that more complex e.g. requiring the constructor closure and access to "this" then they may not work but it all hinges on how the plugin is eventually "registering" the properties. I'm not really a fan of bypassing the "public" API and messing with the internals but I needed to.